# How to make iChat automatically reconnect?

Tags: ichat

My Internet connection breaks quite frequently. And each time iChat shows me "connection is lost" error message. I have to click "OK" and switch my status from Offline to Available. How can I make it do that automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just googled this answer:

http://blogs.oracle.com/safron/entry/make_ichat_reconnect_automatically

Basically, it says to set a cron tab to tell iChat to reconnect every 5 minutes. I have set it to repeat every minute:

```
$ crontab -e
* * * * *       osascript -e 'tell application "iChat" to log in'
```

Answer (score 1):

This version checks that the app is running, so if you close it the script wont reopen it:

```
*/5 * * * * osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to if (processes whose name is "iChat") exists then tell application "iChat" to log in'
```

Found here, by the way: http://www.mikeperham.com/2011/12/30/getting-ichat-to-automatically-reconnect/